# Let C be a fixed integer and define x ∗ y = x + y − C for all x, y $\in$ Z.

Tags: group-theory

Let C be a fixed integer and define x ∗ y = x + y − C for all x, y $\in$ Z.

(i) Prove that (Z, ∗) is a group.

(ii) Prove that (Z, +) is isomorphic to (Z, ∗).

I am so confused by this question. I understand the properties of groups;

Closure, associative, identity and inverse but is this asking me to prove associativity for both x * y and x + y - C or is it saying that x * y is the actually the operation x + y - C.

Comment: The binary operation is $*$.

Answer (score 1):

It's asking for you to prove that the operation $*$ as defined by $x*y=x+y-C$ is associative.

We can show that $(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)$. The lefthand side expands to $(x+y-C)*z=(x+y-C)+z-C= x+y+z-2C$.

Then the righthand side expands to $x*(y+z-C)=x+(y+z-C)-C=x+y+z-2C$, which is the same expression so we have shown associativity.

---

The identity element has to be the fixed integer $C$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of the group, then $x*C=x+C-C=x$. The inverse is $-x+2C$, can you check this yourself?

Comment: Excellent. This is what I had. And inverse would be x + x` - C = 1?

Comment: Try to find the identity element before you try to determine inverses...

Comment: Which in this case would be 0?